# Eliminate the preferences tab in the user profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, tag-watching, ignored-tags

The preferences tab in my user profile here looks like the following.

> [image]

There is a single, actual preference in there, the option to hide ignored tags entirely, and a whole lot of whitespace. The favorite tags are already accessible in a much more convenient and discoverable place in your sidebar, they are entirely redundant here in the preferences.

We all know SE hates preferences, so let's get rid of the whole preferences tab entirely. The favorite/ignored tab is redundant anyway, and the option "hide ignored tags" would fit nicely on the favorite/ignore tags section in the sidebar. At the current place, nobody finds the bloody checkbox anyway if they're not told exactly where to look, moving it to the actual favorite/ignore tag UI would make it vastly more discoverable and is a much more logical place for it.

Comment: I would prefer to have more preferences there, or make one network-wide preferences page that can contain things like "Would you like to receive unread inbox messages via email?". But yes, right now that page is pretty much pointless.

Comment: It would make sense to have that tab if new preferences are going to be added; since Stack Exchange always said to be against user preferences, it doesn't make sense to have that tab just for those two settings.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree with you on that. I would like more preferences too. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178321/183189

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are now more preferences there, and will probably get a few more in the next few months.

Comment: OMG - Preferences!!!