# Should we abolish accepting answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

I just took accepting answers for granted on Stack Exchange, but then I came across Quora, a Q&A site that doesn't have accepted answers (Just to be clear, I'm not suggesting that we make Stack Exchange like Quora - there are tons of reasons why SE >> Quora - but we should be open to other ways of doing things). So, I thought about the pros and cons of accepting answers. What I have here is not an exhaustive list, but just what I came up with off the top of my mind just now.

### Cons of Accepting Answers

1. **The best answer isn't always accepted.** Often, the accepted answer and highest voted answer are not the same. For questions with 20 views, this is okay, but on many popular questions, the accepted answer isn't the highest voted. In my opinion, the highest voted answer is the best answer, since I value the community's opinion above that of the OP. There are cases where this isn't true, but the vast majority of the time, it is.
2. **The Accepted Answer goes to the top.** I wouldn't have any problems with point 1, except that the accepted answer is always at the top. I think that the best answer should be at the top, because some people don't scroll down below it (myself included, oftentimes).
3. **Accepting seals the question.** What I mean is that to accept an answer to a question is almost the same as closing it. People may still go to it and look at it, but definitely fewer. It reduces the traffic.
4. **It discourages better answers.** Accepting an answer doesn't mean it is the best possible answer, it just means that it satisfies the OP. But since accepting an answer seals the question, a person who can provide a better answer is unlikely to stroll along and give that better answer.

### Pros of Accepting Answers

You guys already know these, so I'll just go over a few of them briefly:

1. In many cases, the "right" answer is showcased by sending it to the top of the list.
2. The answerer of the "right" answer is rewarded with 15 rep.
3. New users can reward helpful answers, if they don't have upvoting privileges yet.

### Possible Solutions

I'm not sure how to solve the problems of accepted answers without abolishing them - but I think the pros, primarily the first two, outweigh the cons - which is why I'm asking this question here. How can we fix the problems with accepting answers without getting rid of all the benefits?

Comment: Maybe show a line below questions with accepted answers that encourages those with better answers to still post them.

Comment: @psubsee2003 They're not duplicates. That question asked if they are useful. This question declares that they do cause problems, and asks how we can solve the problems.

Comment: Your #1, #3 and #4 are incorrect. The answer the *poster of the question* found to be the answer to their question is what's being indicated (not the *best* - the best is indicated by the number of votes it receives), and accepting does not "seal the question* because answers can still be posted (and voted on) whether there's an accepted answer there or not. I've posted many answers where there was already an accepted one (and also had the accepted answer changed by the poster afterward more than a few times, which refutes your #4).

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 if you look at the answers, a number of users discussed the use and the solving the problem.  We don't need multiple discussions on the same subject.

Comment: "Accepting seals the question." - I'm not sure this is universally true. The acceptance checkmark can and has been moved if a better answer came along.

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about player behaviour (certainly #1). I can't support that with my own experience, do you have any objective numbers that do?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'm not good enough at SQL to use SE Data Explorer to find out. But I'd be glad if someone more qualified than I could do that research.

Comment: @KenWhite Often the first answer posted that solves the problem is accepted; it's often not the best. And no, it doesn't technically "seal the question," but that's a valid concern - it probably does reduce traffic. However, as for #4, if someone able to produce a better answer *does* visit the question, I think they're pretty likely to post it.

Comment: Consider that Quora has a very different culture of acceptable questions. "What are some uplifting anecdotes?" is a perfectly acceptable Quora question, and one for which having an accepted answer makes no sense. On StackOverflow, that kind of question would never be welcome.

Comment: I think the most reasonable solution, if any action at all is taken, is to order answers by votes, so that the accepted answer isn't always the first shown (the rest of the model would remain untouched). On the other hand, you have to acknowledge that occasionally the highest-voted answer is *not* the "best", but that's much less common than an *accepted answer* not being the best or highest-voted.

Comment: @AnnaLear By sealing the question, I mean that people are less likely to add new answers. If a new answer comes along, then it can be changed, but the chances diminish.

Comment: @psubsee2003 On that question, discussion of solutions to the pitfalls of accepting answers, was if anything, a mere side note. Here, it is the focus of the question.

Comment: @trojandestroy: As I said, voting indicates the *best* answer, and if the poster accepted it must have answered it for them. I'd much rather post an answer that's accepted *and* upvoted*, but I'll be satisfied with posting an answer that gets 10 + votes where the accepted answer only has the accept checkmark (and I'll gladly use information in the higher voted answer over the info in the accepted, because I'm capable of comprehending that the higher vote count means something). Only the person who posted the question can decide which one to accept, and it's *their decision* to make.

Comment: My point is that this attribute of Quora (no accepted answers) is *tied in* with it's other attributes. Quora encourages open-ended questions, which don't lend themselves to accepted answers. StackOverflow insists on objectively answerable questions.

Comment: @KenWhite Good point. However, I disagree about your second point. I'm not saying that we can't scroll down to see the best answer, and be capable of comprehending this. I don't know about other people, but I personally don't always scroll down, especially when the accepted answer is super long. Maybe I just am mentally deficient.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 how is David's 2nd point even related to your objection.  Stack Overflow insists on objectively answerable questions.  There is no disputing that.

Comment: You say "I don't always scroll down". If you were looking for an answer for a **real** problem you have, you *would* scroll, right? If I have an actual problem, I'll read *at least* the first few answers, just to see which approach sounds better suited to my tastes/style. If, on the other hand, you're just browsing, what does it matter?

Comment: @Geobits If the first answer is really long, and it's accepted, then I'll assume it's the best way of doing something. Maybe my problem is just that I'm too lazy to look at more answers.

Comment: Yea, you know the old saying about [assumptions](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=assume), right?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000: So you've never heard what happens when you *assume* ? (Geobits beat me to the link.) Now you want to change one of the fundamental behaviors of SO because you're too lazy to scroll to look at more than the accepted answer? Nah, I don't think so. :-)

Comment: `So you think that objectively answerable questions don't require accepting answers?` What? That's exactly the *opposite* of my comment.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Sorry, I typo. Here's what I meant: So you think that objectively answerable questions require accepting answers?

Comment: I can provide [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1268178/62576) of an answer (one of my own, for clarity) where the accepted answer has only half the votes of the accepted one. If you were looking in the future to an answer to the question asked, can you in all honesty say you'd pick the accepted one over mine? (Or even that scrolling distance is an issue in that one?) I think this is a clear indication that the "problem" you're describing isn't all you suggest.

Comment: I'm saying that they are suited to accepted answers, yes (for the reasons described by everyone here)

Comment: @KenWhite Depending on why I was looking at the question, I probably would scroll down. But not all questions have an accepted answer that short, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693153/mounting-directory-from-parent-system-to-container-in-docker/19058918#19058918).

Comment: But if I were looking to solve that problem, I would notice that there is more than one answer, and I have the common sense to at least look at the one right below the accepted one to see what else is there; I would have definitely noticed the vote disparity and read both answers. I think it's pretty safe to say that the majority of users here can at least notice there are multiple answers and look at at least a couple of them.

Comment: @KenWhite There are cases where a wrong answer is accepted, and the right answer gets pushed below. If I had the same question, and I saw an accepted answer, then I'd assume it to be correct. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances?rq=1). This one got fixed eventually, but it's a flaw in the system.

Comment: @KenWhite You're using the intelligence of users as a justification for a flawed system. It doesn't matter whether or not most users "have common sense to at least look at the one right below," the system is still broken.

Comment: Interesting that you posted a link to a question (that you say is "right", although I'm not sure I agree, for the reasons indicated in Jon Skeet's comment to it) is about allowing someone who gets a wrongly accepted answer to **transfer the acceptance checkmark** to the right answer. In other words, it supports *having accepted answers*, but taking control over who gets the acceptance *away from the poster of the question who has the privilege of deciding which one to accept*.

Comment: And I'm not using it as justification for anything; I'm using it to dispute the flawed reasoning you posted, just as I disputed them in the first comment I posted to this thread. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I linked to it, because the SO question linked in the meta question originally had the wrong answer accepted. I didn't provide the link to say I support the views discussed in the meta, just to have an example of a bad question.

Comment: You used the link (I'm referring to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances?rq=1#comment28850_14933) to support your statement that 
"a wrong answer is accepted, and the right answer gets pushed below". There is no accepted answer in that post. :-) And the irony is what I mentioned above; you've used a post supporting accepting answers, but allowing someone other than the poster to decide who gets the acceptance, as evidence of a flawed design in having acceptance at all.

Comment: @KenWhite In response to your previous comment: 1. Then please explain how incorrect answers can be accepted, and as a result pushed to the top 3. Lower traffic definitely means that there's less likely to be a new answer. 4. There are cases where a new answer comes, but again, there's less likely to be a new answer. In my own experience, I'll get several (3-4) answers, and once I accept the answer, no more come.

Comment: Certainly. @1: The poster can remove the acceptance and award it to a different answer, as has been mentioned by @Anna [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215335/should-we-abolish-accepting-answers?noredirect=1#comment695224_215335). #3: An accepted answer doesn't always mean lesser traffic, or that the traffic that wasn't seen would have posted a better answer. #4: Your own experience is not a reason to change the overall function of SO; as of this moment in time, you've posted a grand total of 11 questions at SO, so your getting 3-4 answers and then no more is hardly evidence.

Comment: To be clear, the point I made about your experience with asking questions was not meant to be derogatory; my experience with asking questions is less than yours. I don't ask many questions. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite As of the link, again, I linked to the meta only as evidence that in the first place that post that the meta discussion was about had an incorrect answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @KenWhite 1. The fact is, it is possible that the asker won't change the accepted answer (e.g. if they don't come here often). And that's a flaw. 3. It doesn't always mean lesser traffic, like when the question has 400 upvotes. But when it's only got 2 upvotes, and it has an accepted answer, the traffic is less likely to come. 4. Unless I'm some subhuman mutant, I doubt I'm alone in my experiences. Of course, I agree that 11 answers are no reason to change an entire site, so feel free to do a data explorer query and share your findings. I'm not good at SQL, so I can't do so.

Comment: @KenWhite Anyway, I think that this discussion isn't productive any more. It's quite obvious that neither of our views are likely to change, and that the site isn't going to change either (I hope I don't sound like I'm conceding right now). I also home I haven't sounded like too much of a jerkbag, and if I have, then I apologize. It's kind of hard to not get annoyed when several people strongly disagree with my (n00by) opinion.

Comment: We're good. :-) A debate is sometimes good, even though most of the SE sites don't allow it. I try very hard not to take anything personally, and you didn't do anything for me to take that way. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, I agree. I'm fairly sure the feature tends to discourage new answers. And *when* new answers come in, accepted answer marks rarely change, often leaving an incorrect or outdated  answer at the top. (And when we raise that concern, we're told that we shouldn't pay attention to the accept mark. So why is it there then?)

The accepted answer feature does, however, have one big advantage. It gives the asker the power to get a workable solution. Without the answerers' hope for the accept mark, many questions would receive answers that may be *correct*, but not helpful for the asker - for example, when the question is about a less-than-optimal practice in a real-world situation where it's the only choice.

I'd be in favour of a compromise. Retain the feature (and the 15-point rep gain that goes with it), but make the accept mark a less prominent signal to the rest of the world:

- stop displaying accepted questions in a special way in lists.
- stop giving accepted answers preferred treatment order-wise.
- stop displaying a giant accept mark; introduce a more toned down way of showing the OP's approval instead.

Comment: My problem with this is that it hurts people that are actually *looking for answers*. If I run a search, I **want** the result list to show me which questions have an accepted answer, so I know which are more likely to have a solution for me. You're looking at this from the angle of an *answerer*.

Comment: @Geobits, spot on. We need to think of the people coming in from google, not the user looking for +15 rep for their answer.

Comment: @Geobits, jmac - you're assuming that the accept mark is always a quality signal. I strongly disagree with that. When I search, I don't care for the accept mark because I know not to trust it. There's a million reasons why people award it and that it was the most helpful answer is only one of them.  I go through each question looking for an answer that actually helps me.

Comment: I'm not assuming it's *always* a quality signal. I'm assuming it is about 90% of the time, though, because that's what I've experienced. I look at multiple questions/answers, too, but **most often**, the accepted flag works.

Comment: FWIW, I do agree that it discourages new answers. When I'm looking for something *to answer*, I skip accepted questions more often than not. I just don't agree with your proposed remedy.

Comment: @Geobits OK, point taken about the quality signal - different people will use SO in different ways. I'm still strongly in favour of abolishing the silly sort order preference though. Show what's most upvoted on the top. Don't let the OP's choice (that they made at a random point in time) trump what the community has upvoted since then

Comment: That I could get behind. I believe I've seen that particular issue brought up a couple times and status-declined, though.

Comment: Why do you think that green checks from users with tinfoil headgear indicate that the question has an answer that _you_ will find useful?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**  ***Definitely*** not for your reasons.  Let me debunk them...

- The best answer isn't always accepted.

  With this, you may have a valid point; I've seen my fair share of answers that are substantially *better*, or simply put, *not as dangerous*, but by no means does acceptance mean that the answer is correct.  I've always interpreted it as this being sufficient to answer the OP's original question.

  This is why one must be careful when reading answers - don't just go for the accepted one right off the bat, but see if there is more substance in a higher upvoted answer.

  This is more *caveat lectorus* than anything else.
- The Accepted Answer goes to the top.

  You're probably right about this, but this is likely an issue [with answer ordering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214300/175248) than anything else.
- Accepting seals the question.

  In a sense, it *could*, but if a better solution exists, and the community identifies it, then there's absolutely no reason why someone else couldn't come along later and post a better answer.  If the OP also agrees, then they could award the "accepted" answer to them, instead.  In fact, this past Winterbash, there was a hat exclusively for that (Buccaneer).

  The mentality of acceptance meaning resolved answer also breaks down in the face of bounties on questions with accepted answers; perhaps the answer that is accepted doesn't sufficiently cover the question as well as originally thought, or more detail is preferred.
- It discourages better answers.

  This is patently false.  If you could provide some scenarios in which this is the case, I'd be happy to retract this statement, but by and large, I've seen that, if there is a better answer out there, then people *tend* to post it.

Comment: `I've seen that, if there is a better answer out there, then people tend to post it.`.... and if there is a worse answer out there, people tend to post that too.

Comment: I don't think the point about discouraging answers is completely incorrect. I'm not versed enough in statistics to do the  analysis, but I bet if you'd look at the likelihood of a question receiving an answer before and after it is accepted, you'd find a big change.

Comment: @Pëkka:  I'd like to see some statistics about it too.  That's why I left it mostly open-ended.  I don't believe that this occurs, but I can be convinced.

Comment: @psubsee2003:  You've got a good point in "worse" answers, and I won't disagree that they're posted either.  But, typically, the worst of the answers is downvoted into oblivion, and the answers which are actually better are indeed voted up.

Comment: @Mako to not always, some are worse, but not awful. They just get posted and forgotten so they sit there with no votes and few views.

Comment: @psubsee2003: That feels more like question/answer rot, more than anything else.  If the answer isn't seen by a lot of people, then yeah, it kind of gets forgotten about.

Answer (score 1):

### Executive Summary

You seem to have three faulty premises:

1. The goal is to provide the 'best' answer to each question
2. Accepting an answer reduces visibility of other answers
3. Accepting an answer prevents future improvement

### 'Best' Answer

When I come across a question through Google, my primary goal is to solve my problem. The accepted answer checkmark tells me that, for the person who asked the question, the accepted answer works. That is a hugely valuable signal to me I would hate to lose.

Upvoters may not have tested the code. The person asking probably has. They have tried the solution and it worked. No amount of upvotes can tell me if that is the case, and for many questions the gain of testing multiple answers is less than implementing the accepted answer solution.

### Visibility

If I see an accepted 5 upvote answer and read to the end, I will notice that the answer below it has 60 upvotes. When there is a large gap, I will likely read through the second answer as well, and then I have two resources to look over to solve the problem. Browsing [answers that got the populist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist), many are alternative methods, slightly more optimized, but not dramatically better than the accepted answer for someone looking for a quick fix.

The point is that even though the accepted answer goes first, the other answers are still there, and visible, and the bigger the contrast in score, the more of a signal toward the potential worth I have to make a decision on how to spend my time. If I need a quick fix, the accepted answer will probably suit my needs 99 times out of 100 or more.

### Future Improvement

Looking back at those populist badges, you will see that there are several where the answer is one that provides an updated answer to the question. For instance, this question provides an answer for a later version of the software:

[Change UITextField and UITextView Cursor / Caret Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606007/change-uitextfield-and-uitextview-cursor-caret-color/18945907#18945907)

The accepted answer is pre-iOS7, and the most upvoted is for iOS7+. Both are good answers. And having an accepted answer hasn't prevented people from adding answers or from finding the answer they were looking for an upvoting it.

Comment: Re "Best" answer - it's often enough the *wrong* signal, and no one except the OP has the power to change it. That sucks, big time. You have a point with the second paragraph though

Comment: @Pëkka, I don't know about that. Of the 6.4 million questions on SO, [1.7 million have only one answer which is accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A1..1+hasaccepted%3Atrue). That means 25% of our questions are giving the right signal off the bat. Someone can dig in to the data explorer, but I would wager that there are more accepted answers that have the most upvotes than non-accepted answers with the most upvotes, further increasing the usefulness of that signal.

Comment: But look at your example question. There is going to be an iOS6 answer at the top, signaling "this was the solution", for all eternity. That happens often enough, and no one but the OP (who may have long gone) has the power to ever change it. How is that not broken? And it'll become brokener and brokener the older the data pool gets.

Comment: @Pëkka, if you are looking for the answer to that question, does the current format not allow you to still find it easily? Even the first answer has been edited to point out what it applies to. Nothing is preventing someone from creating a new question explaining how to do it in iOS7+ as a separate question either. The info is there, accessible, and clearly marked. How is this a strike against having an accepted answer exactly?

Comment: `Nothing is preventing someone from creating a new question`  that may very easily end up being a duplicate though. The accepted answer system simply isn't a good fit for questions that change in time. If you ask me, we either need a way for the community to change the accepted answer on abandoned questions, or to get rid of it altogether.