# Answers should be sorted strictly according to upvotes and not give precedence to the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Upvotes are almost always a much better indicator of a good answer than an answer actually being accepted by the question's author. Often times the question's author will accept a poor answer. Thus, the first answer to be displayed to the public should not necessarily be the accepted answer.

We want to cater to the general public who will be viewing the discussion. We want to show them the most relevant answers first. The answers that are most relevant to the general public are the ones with the most upvotes, not the answer that the question's author accepted. The collection of people who are voting almost surely do a better job of ranking answers than the single question's author. Afterall, these voters represent the general public that we are trying to cater to.

Comment: Related: [Do accepted answers still serve a useful purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose)